# android livedata not working in Activity , viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, mvvm

Hello I have recently encountered a situation where observing is not possible in livedata, so I am going to ask a question

It's too basic, but I don't know why it doesn't work, so I need your help.

If you give me a little teaching, I would be grateful

my SignUpActivity

```
class SignUpActivity : BaseKotlinActivity<ActivitySignUpBindingImpl, SignUpViewModel>() {

    override val layoutResourceId: Int get() = R.layout.activity_sign_up

    override val viewModel: SignUpViewModel by viewModel()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivitySignUpBindingImpl>(this, layoutResourceId)

        binding.apply {
            lifecycleOwner = this@SignUpActivity
            signUpViewModel = viewModel
        }

        viewModel?.apply {
            signUpStep.observe(this@SignUpActivity, Observer {
                when (it) {
                    SignUpStep.SIGN_UP -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, SignUpFragment(), "SignUpFragment").commit()
                    SignUpStep.PASSWORD -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, SignUpPasswordFragment(), "SignUpPasswordFragment").commit()
                    SignUpStep.PHONE_CERTIFICATION -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, SignUpPhoneCertificationFragment(), "SignUpPhoneCertificationFragment").commit()
                    else -> Unit
                }
                Log.d("Test Checked1", "${signUpStep.value}")
            })
        }

    }
}
```

my viewModel

```
private val _signUpStep = MutableLiveData<SignUpStep>(SignUpStep.SIGN_UP)
    val signUpStep: LiveData<SignUpStep>
        get() = _signUpStep

    fun moveStep(view: View, newSignUpStep: SignUpStep) {
        val oldSignUpStep = _signUpStep.value
        _signUpStep.value = newSignUpStep

        Log.d( "Test Checked","moveStep: $oldSignUpStep -> $newSignUpStep")
    }
```

log

```
Test Checked1: SIGN_UP
moveStep: SIGN_UP -> PASSWORD
moveStep: PASSWORD -> PASSWORD
moveStep: PASSWORD -> PASSWORD
```

If you check the log, you can see that the moveStep changes normally. Then signUpSteop has changed normally, but it is not received in the observe of livedata, because the screen does not move and the log does not appear.

I'm just wondering if the code is wrong or what's wrong. Can you help me?

For reference, signUpStep is changing in Fragment and livedata is constantly being observed in activity.

Comment: Can you post the Fragment code that updates the viewModel?

Comment: My guess is that your Fragments aren't using the same ViewModel instance as your Activity.

Comment: hi lvan, It doesn't do anything in my fragment, since the activity is observing the data in the ViewModel anyway, do I need to do it in the fragment? It’s a simple question because of my lack of skills.

Comment: No, you should be able to update the viewModel from the Fragment and have the changes propagate to all that are listening to ViewModel changes. I need to see your Fragment code to verify it's using the same ViewModel instance as your Activity.

Comment: Thanks lvan I was able to solve it thanks to your advice